# Occasionally Unresponsive Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

Occasionally, my keyboard and mouse suddenly go into some unresponsive state.

Symptoms of this state:

- Seems to occur randomly, sometimes multiple times per day
- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> seems to be the only way to exit this unresponsive state.
- There is no audible or on-screen notification of this change
- While in the state, the Caps Lock and Scroll Lock LEDs flash back and forth

I tried disabling all startup programs, but the issue still occurs.

The keyboard and mouse are both generic Dell ones.

What is causing this behavior?  Where do I disable it?

Comment: Try a keyboard you know is working properly.

Comment: I will try a new keyboard and follow up.  However, the issue also locks the mouse, so I assume it's an issue with the computer or a program.

Comment: do you have a KVM switch? This is a desktop machine?

Comment: Yes.  I have a KVM switch (by IOGEAR) between two desktop machines.  I have had no issues with it.  Using the external button, it switches every time.  Are IOGEAR KVMs known for being buggy like this and freezing the keyboard and mouse?

Comment: @CodyPace It happened once with a new keyboard, so it's not that.

Comment: @Yorik I will disconnect the KVM and see if the problem goes away.  Since I don't know the cause, it might be a day or so before I have enough confidence that the KVM is the cause.

Comment: Are any of your other peripherals acting up? Do flash drives, etc. work in the usb ports. If everything is malfunctioning connecting to these ports then it could be a motherboard problem.  You could also try uninstalling their drivers and rebooting to let them reinstall the drivers.

Comment: @CodyPace No other peripherals seem to be affected.  Interesting thought though.  I'll leave the KVM connected normally, and leave a keyboard connected to my primary computer.  When the issue happens, I'll see if that other keyboard works.

Comment: Some KVM switches have a magic keypress, such as a double-tap on scroll lock, which sets the KVM to switchable mode, you'd use the arrows keys or something to change the KVM switch target. The blinking lights and the escape key working suggests a programmable mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a KVM Switch programmable mode, rather than a bug. It looks like on some packages, the control key is an alternate mode-switching key and a double-tap (a common occurrence) puts you in programmable mode.

I am reminded of the Windows sequence of 5 rapid taps of the shift key putting you in Accessible mode. Many people would inadvertently enable Sticky Keys while playing FPS games.

From a random IOGEAR KVM Switch manual:

> By default, all of the following commands begin by pressing the
>   [Scroll Lock] key twice. A few PC key
>   - boards and all Apple keyboards do not have a [Scroll Lock] key.  If you have one of these keyboards you  must use the alternate toggle key
>   of [Control] instead.
>   [...]
>
> You may enter advanced hotkey mode by pressing and
>   holding [Num Lock] on the number pad, then pressing the [-] key on the
>   number pad and immediately releasing both keys.
>   [...]
>   If you have done this correctly the Caps Lock and Scroll Lock
>   lights on the keyboard should begin flashing. This means you are in
>   hotkey mode, which will be shortened to just [HKM] below. If you are
>   having trouble entering hotkey mode press [Esc] and try again.

Comment: That was it.  Pressing Ctrl twice is what caused the seemingly random behavior.  That could easily interfere with shortcut keys.  I found the manual for my KVM and changed it to Scroll Lock.  Problem solved.  Thanks!